# Windows 10 taskbar window preview like windows 7

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Does anyone know if there is a way to restore the Windows 7 taskbar "window preview" functionality into Windows 10?

As per the picture, I'd like to have the single line preview, without the window preview, just the way it was in the past.

What I want vs I don't want:

[image]

Comment: Some quick testing on my end indicates that the closest you can get is to disable thumbnails for the icons that have more than one window open. To do this, open regedit.exe, navigate to: 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband', create a new DWORD value named 'NumThumbnails' and leave its value set to 0x00000000. Log off & back on.

Comment: @KeithMiller Thank you very much, that is definitely a huge step forward (which, as is often the case with Microsoft's "innovation" these days, a step backward (in time, in any case). Thank you very much. Your logon / logoff is the more "sanitary" procedure, however I just restarted the explorer process. Sorry there seems to be no way to mark this as answered.

Comment: I'll repost as an answer rather than a comment so you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick testing on my end indicates that the closest you can get is to disable thumbnails for the icons that have more than one window open. To do this:

1. open regedit.exe
2. Navigate to:

   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband
3. Create a new DWORD value named 'NumThumbnails' and leave its value set to 0x00000000
4. Log off & back on

Keith